# How to create CSV file without unnecessary spaces

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I use the **xls2csv** binary in order to translate **XLS** doc to **CSV** in my linux red-hat machine,

example: ( from man page )

```
 xls2csv -x "1252spreadsheet.xls" -b WINDOWS-1252 -c "ut8csvfile.csv" -a UTF-8
```

But I noticed about the following problems - **steps 1,2** ( the following problems cause many troubles in my bash script )

**THE PROBLEMS ARE:**

**(1)** CSV file include unnecessary spaces (on the left side of word or on the right side of word)

Example of wrong syntax in CSV

```
 ,"/var/adm/sys ldd/all  /Comm/logs   ","WORD "," WORD"
```

Example of right syntax in csv

```
 ,"/var/adm/sys ldd/all  /Comm/logs",WORD,WORD
```

**(2)** quotation marks appears in the CSV even if word is (one word between separators), in fact we not need quotation marks in case of SINGLE word between the separators ( separator “,” )

Example of wrong syntax in CSV

```
 ," WORD ",
```

Example of right syntax in csv

```
 ,WORD,
```

Please advice how to solve the problems as described here in order to create "clean csv file" according to **steps 1,2**

implementation could be with **awk,sed ,perl one liner, or any solution under bash** script

Example of CSV file before the fix

```
 1,"/var/adm/sys ldd/all  /Comm/logs",34356,"234245 ",24245
 2,"/var/adm/sys ldd/all
 /Comm/debugs.txt"," 45356",435,"  578 58976  "
 3,"   add this line in crontab    :",34356,"234245 ",24245
 4,"1.0348    54 35.5"," 45356","   435","578 "
 4,"1 2 "," 45356 95857 ","   435","578 "
 5,"1 2 "," 45356 95857 ","   "435","578" "
 6,"1.0348    54 35.5"," 45356"," "4"""    ""35","578 "
 7,"1.0348    54 35.5",""45356",""4"""""35,"578 "
```

Example of correct CSV file ( after the fix )

```
 1,"/var/adm/sys ldd/all  /Comm/logs",34356,234245,24245
 2,"/var/adm/sys ldd/all
 /Comm/debugs.txt",45356,435,"578 58976"
 3,"add this line in crontab    :",34356,234245,24245
 4,"1.0348    54 35.5",45356,435,578 
 4,"1 2","45356 95857",435,578
 5,"1 2","45356 95857","435,578" 
 6,"1.0348    54 35.5",45356,"4"""    ""35,578
 7,"1.0348    54 35.5",""45356",""4"""""35,578
```

Commas cannot appear within fields.

Note the explicit newline contained within a field of `line 2`.

When a field is within double quotes and contains no white space (e.g. line 7 `""45356"`), those double quotes must not be removed because that whole field including those quotes is an encoded password

Comment: the basic concept is this - if we have space/spaces on the left side of WORD or on the right side of WORD then need to remove the quotes ( and that only if WORD is single word )

Comment: the WORD ""45356" not have space on the right side or the left side therefore no need to remove the quotes

Comment: because word can be password , and passwrd can be for example H^3gb"""

Comment: or for example """(&GF%R$"

Comment: I will Appreciate if you can help me to update my question , I think because your experience your update will be more clearly then my update

Comment: yes they good example of what I need (1-7 are the csv serial numbers )

Comment: Ed Morton - thx for the update , I hope I will get answers for my question , do you think solution can be very complicated ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147016/how-to-create-csv-file-without-unnecessary-spaces

Comment: possible duplicate of [xls2csv + disable empty spaces from the XLS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000101/xls2csv-disable-empty-spaces-from-the-xls)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { gsub(/(^"?[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*"?$)/, "", $i); if ($i ~ /[[:space:]]/) $i = "\"" $i "\"" } } 1' file
```

Output:

```
1,"/var/adm/sys ldd/all  /Comm/logs",34356,234245,24245
2,"/var/adm/sys ldd/all  /Comm/debugs.txt",45356,435,"578 58976"
3,"add this line in crontab    :",34356,234245,24245
4,"1.0348    54 35.5",45356,435,578
4,"1 2","45356 95857",435,578
5,"1 2","45356 95857","435,578"
```

Only thing is that values can't have commas on it e.g. `"This is, a value."`.

Comment: I found a bug - for example in case the last line is --> 4,"1 2 "," 45356 95857 ","   "435","578 "      , no need to remove the quote before 435 need to remove the quote only on the left side or right side because some times quote is part of word

Comment: @maihabunash Doesn't my script produce the output you expect?

Comment: @maihabunash what ? This produces the exact example output you have in your question ?

Comment: after allot of testing I found that your code not support the example in line 7 ( in the CSV file ) , your code print that: 7,"1.0348    54 35.5","45356,"4"""""35,578

Comment: as you know in case of no spaces between seperator no need to remove the quotes - example - ""4"""""35 ( no need to remove the quote ,

Answer (score 0):

Try this perl one liner:

```
perl -i -nle 'chomp($_);$_=~s/\s*"\s*/"/sg;print "$_"' file
```