# xls2csv + disable empty spaces from the XLS

Tags: linux, excel, bash, perl, csv

I use the **xls2csv** binary in order to translate XLS doc to CSV in my linux red-hat machine,

in some cases the XLS doc have space before word or after word

example of XLS file ( word3 have one space on the right side )

```
 word1 word2 "word3 "
 word1 word2 "word3 "
 word1 word2 "word3 "
```

after I runs the **xls2csv**

as:

```
  xls2csv -x "1252spreadsheet.xls" -b WINDOWS-1252 -c "ut8csvfile.csv" -a UTF-8 )
```

I notice that word3 in the csv doc have the same space on word3 as in XLS ( "word3 " )

please advice how to configure the **xls2csv** binary in order to disable empty spaces???? from the XLS doc , so I will get the CSV without empty spaces ?

**FROM XLS2CSV MAN PAGE:**

```
 man xls2csv
 XLS2CSV(1)            User Contributed Perl Documentation           XLS2CSV(1)

 NAME
       xls2csv - A script that recodes a spreadsheetâs charset and saves as CSV.

    DESCRIPTION
        This script will recode a spreadsheet into a different character set and output     the recoded data as a csv file.

          The script came about after many headaches from dealing with Excel   spreadsheets from clients that were being
       received in various character sets.

  OPTIONS
           -x     : filename of the source spreadsheet
           -b     : the character set the source spreadsheet is in (before)
           -c     : the filename to save the generated csv file as
           -a     : the character set the csv file should be converted to (after)
           -q     : quiet mode
           -s     : print a list of supported character sets
           -h     : print help message
           -v     : get version information
           -W     : list worksheets in the spreadsheet specified by -x
           -w     : specify the worksheet name to convert (defaults to the first worksheet)
           -n     : specify the worksheet number to convert (you cannot use this option with -w)
           -f     : force the worsheet to be fully parsed. This disables the feature that skips rows when the first cell is blk
```

Comment: Essentially the same question asked here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147016/4667

Comment: Not the same - here I ask how to solve the problem from the xls2csv command

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995753/how-to-create-csv-file-without-unnecessary-spaces

Comment: As a constructive comment now, aren't those "extra spaces" already present in the source XLS file? If that so, it would be rather unexpected to find an option in xls2csv that would fix the broken input data. As of myself I would stick with the approach you had yesterday, that is somehow "fixing afterward" the CSV file. But as you have discovered this is less trivial than expected. Maybe you should have edited your previous question(s) by providing an updated example of "broken CSV" exhibiting all the special cases that came up from the various comments and/or answers you already have.

Comment: YES the spaces present in the XLS file

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it sounds like you're using the wrong tool.  Maybe you should write a script that uses Spreadsheet::ParseExcel to read/parse the xls file and then apply whatever field reformatting that is needed.  Once that is done use Text::CSV_XS to output the csv data.

EDIT: I meant to post that as a comment, but I guess it could also be taken as an answer.

Comment: not agree xls2csv is very good tool , its translete the XLS to CSV axactly as XLS structure

Comment: must be some way to put some flag in the xls2csv to disable that